# Looping through arrays inside an array in twig

Tags: arrays, loops, twig

I am using twig for rendering my template. I have a multidimensional array and trying to list out that array. My array structure is as follows

```
Array [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => user1
        [email] => user2@gmail.com
        [company_id] => 136
        [photos] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [company_id] => 136
                        [photo] => 5af13c3287f66.jpeg
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [company_id] => 136
                        [photo] => default.jpeg
                    )
          )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => user2
        [email] => user2@gmail.com
        [company_id] => 137
        [photos] => []
    )
```

And in my view page displaying this like

```
 {% for users in userlist %}
 <tr>
     <td>{{ users.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ users.email}}<td>
     <td> #pic1 - if available </td>
     <td> #pic2 - if available </td>
  </tr>
```

How can I loop through the second array and display its values if available. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just use another loop:

```
{% for users in userlist %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ users.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ users.email}}<td>
    {% for photo in users.photos %}
      <td><img src="{{ photo.photo }}" /></td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Note: It doesn't make much sense to have an array called photos whose elements don't represent "photos" but instead have another property called "photo" themselves. It would probably make more sense to call the subproperty `filename` or `path` or `url`; so that `{{ photo.photo }}` becomes `{{ photo.path }}`.